# PT transformation of a spinor

Tags: special-relativity, symmetry, spinors, parity, time-reversal-symmetry

By demanding the the Dirac equation be invariant under general Lorentz transformations, we get an equation for the transformation matrix of a Dirac spinor,
$$ S^{-1}(\Lambda) \gamma^\mu S(\Lambda) = {\Lambda^\mu}_\nu \gamma^\nu, $$
such that the spinor transforms as
$$ \psi \quad\stackrel{{\Lambda^\mu}_\nu}\to\quad S(\Lambda)\psi $$
If we go through this three times for
$$ {(\Lambda_P)^\mu}_\nu = {diag(+1,-1,-1,-1)^\mu}_\nu \\ {(\Lambda_T)^\mu}_\nu = {diag(-1,+1,+1,+1)^\mu}_\nu \\ {(\Lambda_{PT})^\mu}_\nu = {diag(-1,-1,-1,-1)^\mu}_\nu $$
the relevant equations can be solved by
$$\begin{align} S(\Lambda_P) &= \pm\gamma^0 \\ S(\Lambda_T) &= \pm\gamma^1\gamma^3 \qquad\leftarrow\text{(wrong! see answer below!)} \\ S(\Lambda_{PT}) &= \pm\gamma^5 \end{align}$$
Naively, I would expect that since $P\circ T=PT$, we would also have $S(\Lambda_P)S(\Lambda_T)=S(\Lambda_{PT})$. This is obviously not the case. Why?

Answer (score 2):

I find that your $S(\Lambda_T)$ should be  $\gamma^1\gamma^2\gamma^3$ as that flips the $\gamma^0$ three times, but flips the other three gammas twice.

But be careful the actual action of $T$ on  spinor  fields and states works differently:
On fields
$$
{\mathsf T}^{-1} \hat \psi(x,t) {\mathsf T}= \eta_T {\mathcal T} \hat \psi(x,-t)
$$
where $\mathsf T$ is antiunitary and ${\mathcal T}$ is a unitary matrix obeying   $$
{\mathcal T} \gamma^\mu {\mathcal T}^{-1} =(\gamma^\mu)^T
$$
The form of ${\mathcal T}$ in terms of the gamma matrices depeneds on the representation because if  $\gamma^\mu\to S\gamma^\mu S^{-1}$ then ${\mathcal T}\to S^T{\mathcal T} S$.

On the  wavefunction $\phi(x,t)= \langle 0|\hat \psi(x,t)|\phi\rangle$ of a single-particle state $|\phi\rangle$  we have (in four dimensions where ${\mathcal T}$ is skew symmetric)
$$
\phi(x,t)\to - \eta_T^* {\mathcal T}^{-1} \phi^*(x,-t)
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I still have a question: QFT books like Peskin&Schroeder or Schwartz use $\mathcal T=\gamma^1\gamma^3$, which does indeed fulfill your second equation. But where does it come from? And why does it work differently for $S(\Lambda_T)$?

Comment: There is little connection between your def of $S(\Lambda)T)$ and what is called "time reversal".Your def would  work  for  *time reflection* in   Euclidean siganture, but that operation  turns particles into antiparticles. What is called "time reversal" today adds  an extra charge conjugation to  time reflection so as to undo this, and then adds a complex conjugation in changing to Minkowski signature. P&S formula is basis-dependent are most such textbook expressions. That's why I gave the transformation formula.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for clearing that up. To be sure, let me try: 1) $\mathcal T = K \exp(\pm i\pi S_y)$? 2) Time reversal ($\mathsf T,\mathcal T$) = time reflection $(\Lambda_T)$ + charge conjugation ($\mathsf C,\mathcal C$) + complex conjugation ($K$)? If so, 3) where does your second equation (transformation formula) come from? and 4) why is $(\Lambda_T)$ time reflection in *Euclidean* space?